# Why do strings with newlines do not match regular expressions in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, newline

I have a String `string` that contains a newline (`\n`). When I try to match it with a regular expression `pattern` it returns false, although there should be a match.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class ExgExTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = ".*[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}.*";
        String string  = "123ABC\nDEF";

        if (string.matches(pattern)) {
            System.out.println("Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Does not match.");
        }

    } // END: main()

} // END: class
```

How can I match multiline strings with a regular expression?

Comment: `matches` test the regex against the *whole* string, not par to the string. If you want to get any match, use pattern and matcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I match multiline strings with a regular expression?

You need to use `DOTALL` (`s`) flag for this:

```
String pattern = "(?s).*[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}.*";
```

Take note of `(?s)` which will make `DOT` match new lines also.

Comment: Nice answer. I'll also give you a +1, when I reached 15 reputation.

Comment: You're welcome, accepting the answer is good enough. However you have 15+ rep now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Pattern.quote(pattern)` to escape all special characters in the pattern.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).